# Is there anyone can apply a performance report for elasticsearch bulk?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

As I search many in google, I still don't find a answer.

Is there anyone can apply a performance report for elasticsearch bulk?

I want to know the upper limit of the bulk.

You can tell the max speed for it with what kind of specifications of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is to look at using rally to benchmark your cluster to provide that answer - https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/